# Recommendations for mobile multi-platform app with ar

Tags: android, ios, mobile, artificial-intelligence, augmented-reality

I'm investigating tech-stack for application with following requirements:

- mobile (iOS, Android)
- multi-platform (one code base)
- augmented reality functionalities
- object recognition / tracking

In short: it will recognize objects on view from device's camera and show special, animated information about it.

My short list after research is: Xamarin/Flutter + ARCore + TensorFlow Lite. But I feel is not the final one.

What technologies/framework/SDK would you recommend for such kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We decided to use (maybe it helps someone):

**Flutter + Unity 3D + AR Foundation + flutter_unity_widget**

1. *Flutter* - nice multiplatform experience
2. *Unity 3D & AR Foundation* - enough AR and Image Tracking functionality
3. *flutter_unity_widget* - to merge together aforementioned technologies

Comment: It definitely helps!  Thank you for posting what worked for you!